# Переместить элемент с индексом K на место элемента с индексом M, сдвигая при этом остальные элементы массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Дано массив `arr`. Переместить элемент с индексом `K` на место элемента с индексом `M`, сдвигая при этом остальные элементы массива.
Решил это так:

```
    void ExtendArray(int &cnt, double *&arr, int k, int m)
{
    double *newARR = new double[cnt];

    if (k == m)
        return;
    else if (k < m) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            newARR[i] = arr[i];
        for (int i = k+1; i <= m; i++)
            newARR[i-1] = arr[i];
        newARR[m] = arr[k];
        for (int i = m + 1; i < cnt; i++)
            newARR[i] = arr[i];
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            newARR[i] = arr[i];
        newARR[m] = arr[k];
        for(int i=m+1; i<k; i++)
            newARR[i+1] = arr[i];
        for(int i=k+1; i<cnt; i++)
            newARR[i] = arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;

    arr = newARR;
}
```

Но мне кажется, что получилось не совсем оптимально. Предложите свое решение этого задания.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем тут понадобилось выделять еще один массив и удалять старый. И почему ничего не делается, если `k > m`

Comment: Обновил вопрос!

Comment: Что значит "получилось не совсем хорошо"  что это за формулировка вопроса такая ??  Скажите конкретно какая проблема в вашем решении, и приведите пример входных данных (тоесть массив) и то, что должно получится на выходе (тоесть выходной массив).

Comment: Я хочу узнать как решить эту задачу лучше, оптимальнее что-ли. Мое решение работает правильно

Comment: @BorisMakhlin да какая у вас задача то, приведите примеры

Comment: @BorisMakhlin, очевидно, в плане оптимизации можно обойтись без создания нового массива. примерно так (для случая K < M):  tmp = array[K]; for (i = K..M) array[i] = array[i+i]; Array[M] = tmp

Comment: когда есть трудности с правильной формулировкой вопроса, нужно приводить пример:  "вот, например у меня есть это, я хочу получать то то "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другими словами, вам нужно выполнить обыкновенный циклический сдвиг участка массива между элементами K и M на один элемент вправо или влево. Готовое решение в стандартной библиотеке C++ - `std::rotate`

```
void ExtendArray(double arr[], int k, int m)
{
  if (k < m)
    std::rotate(arr + k, arr + k + 1, arr + m + 1);
  else if (k > m)
    std::rotate(arr + m, arr + k, arr + k + 1);
}
```

В любом случае, заводить новый массив никакого смысла нет. Достаточно скопировать элемент K в сторону, скопировать остальные элементы участка на 1 влево или вправо и затем поместить изначально скопированный элемент на место M.

Answer (score 0):

Тип **double** простой тип без внутренних связей (адресами памяти). Можно обойтись простым переносом данных. Индексы очень маленького типа у вас, можно уже переходить на тип **size_t**. Размер **cnt** передаёте по ссылке, это очень накладно для проги считывать постоянно по ссылке не изменилось ли количество. Нужно передавать по значению.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -c extarr.cpp
# include <string.h>
void ExtendArray(double * arr, size_t k, size_t m) {
  if (k == m)        return;
  double arrk = arr[k];
  if (k < m)  memmove(arr+k,arr+k+1,(size_t)(arr+m)-(size_t)(arr+k));
  else        memmove(arr+m+1,arr+m,(size_t)(arr+k)-(size_t)(arr+m));
  arr[m] = arrk ; }
```